# Ajax isn't working on website

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

For my personal site I want to insert a simple ajax server clock into my website, but for some reason it's not showing up in the header. Here's the Javascript code

```
var httpxml;
try {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e) {
  // Internet Explorer
  try {
    httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      alert("ur browser doesn't support ajax m8, try reinstalling windows 95");
      return false;
    }
  } 
}

function stateck() {
  if(httpxml.readyState==4) {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;
  }
}

var url="ajax-server-clock-demock.php";
url=url+"?sid="+Math.random();
httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
httpxml.send(null);
tt=timer_function();
}

function timer_function(){
  var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime=setTimeout('AjaxFunction();',refresh)
}
```

And in php file

```
<?Php
echo date("d/m/y : H:i:s", time());
?>
```

Lastly in the header

```
<time>bacon</time>
```

Comment: *"try reinstalling windows 95"* - where'd you get that script from?

Comment: I added it as a joke lol.

Comment: Well, I sure got a *chuckle  out of it* ;-)

Comment: Some formatting issues, anyways why do you think it's not working, maybe the 'time' element is conflicting?

Comment: TBH, JS isn't my *forté*. However, I know some and by the looks of `document.getElementById("time")` there isn't a div id of that name. Then this `url=url+"?sid` that needs to be called through a GET. There might be more but that's about the scope of my knowledge with client-side code. I'm mostly serverside.

Comment: I've reformatted your code and found a stray `}`. If that's your code as is, maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I would have to see more code in context because several things can make this not work, in the mean time, there are multiple issues with your script, among others:

You did setTimeout(). That would only execute once, assuming you want the clock to update every second you need to use:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Oh, also, you need to do something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0];
```

Instead of getElementById()

OR add an id to your element like:

```
<time id="mytime"></time>
```

And then you can call:

```
document.getElementById('mytime');
```

got it?

And also, where is declared this AjaxFunction() you are calling in setTimeout?

Also, there are much better ways to do a clock... and you should really consider using jQuery or something like that, will make your life much easier when doing AJAX, DOM manipulation and etc...